# How to understand "in the end bed"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> It was empty except for Ron, who was still lying motionless **in the end bed**.

The phrase "*in the end bed*" looks strange to me. I've never seen **'end'** is used like that. Usually, I see "*at the end of*" or "*in the end of*". I think it's used as an adjective here, but according to the dictionaries I consulted, 
'end'- when used as an adjective- means *final or ultimate* as in *the end result*, which isn't fit for this context.

What does "*in the end bed*" mean exactly? Is it a normal use of the word '**end**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *end* is being used as an adjective.

You can contrast it with a situation when there are three beds and it's the one in between two others being discussed:

> In the *middle* bed.

Or, in this particular case, it's the same as saying:

> In the bed *at the end*.

You could also consider *end* in this case as being synonymous with *last* (which may make more sense to you than *final* or *ultimate* because the sentence is describing a spatial position):

> In the *last* bed.

Comment: Is this use of 'end' common?

Comment: I'd say it's normal. I frequently say and hear things like *I'll take the end seat* or *I'll eat the end piece*.